# Почему появляется ошибка в при работе с swiperefreshlayout android?

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

У себя в приложение хочу реализовать обновление списка входящих сообщений при помощи swiperefreshlayout. Делаю по этому [примеру](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/swiperefreshlayout.php). Если я правильно все прочитал и понял, то сначала нужно завернуть view в xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager" />


    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

дальше нужно сделать инициализацию в том классе в котором вы используете тот элемент который вы хотите повторно заполнить:

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.refresh_1);
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
```

не забыть прописать метод:

```
@Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        sent();
    }
```

в методе `onRefresh` я вызываю ту функцию, которая тянет данные с сервера и потом заполняет мой `RecyclerView`. Но у меня ошибка появляется:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.developer_4.test_login, PID: 9886
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout$OnRefreshListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.developer_4.test_login.Tabs.Sent.onCreateView(Sent.java:71)
```

насколько я понял суть ошибки, то она означает что мы вызываем функцию `setOnRefreshListener` указывая в теле функции нулевой объект. Я не понимаю что нужно передавать функции что-бы она работала так как нужно, я просто первый раз с ней работаю и возможно не знаю каких-то премудростей.

### UPDATE

метод `onCreateView` который используется в фрагменте:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_received, container, false);
        recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
       mSwipeRefreshLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.refresh_1);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                sent();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: в каком классе у вас - mSwipeRefreshLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.refresh_1);?

Comment: он находится onCreateView, это фрагмент у меня

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, у вас mSwipeRefreshLayout null. Вы либо опечатались в id либо не ту разметку используете

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я вроде проверил, все нормально, `id` правильный и разметка та что нужно, я же использовал эту разметку и до добавления свайпа.

Comment: То есть приведённый кусок разметки находится в файле `fragment_received.xml`? А приведённый метод в классе `com.example.developer_4.test_login.Tabs.Sent`?

Comment: @woesss вы как всегда правы)) спасибо что указали на мою ошибку, я вот думаю может удалить вопрос, а то он не несет никакой образовательной цели?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вы как модератор, как думаете удалять вопрос или пусть висит дальше?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, если вы в ответе напишите как так получилось и как ошибка нашлась то вопрос может быть полезным и удалять его нужды не будет)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я не уверен что моя ошибка будет кому-то полезна, но я последую вашему совету.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, это очень частая ошибка и чем больше о ней будет информации в интернете - тем лучше)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ на данный вопрос довольно прост и банален. Я ошибся при указании названий `xml` файлов в методе `onViewCreated`. Так как у меня два фрагмента и соответственно два файла разметки, то я ошибся указав в каждом из двух методов `onViewCreated` один файл разметки. А нужно было для фрагмента `Send` подключать разметку `fragment_sent.xml`. Приложение слетало из-за того что класс фрагмента не видел в указанной ему разметке нужный элемент.

Надеюсь такую тупую ошибку допустил только я, но все-же может мой ответ будет кому-то полезен.

Answer (score 1):

```
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            sent();
        }
    });
```

попробуйте так

Comment: нет не помогло к сожалению, ошибка та же.

Comment: @Andrew Goroshko это у вас в активити или в другом классе?

Comment: данная конструкция используется в фрагменте.

Comment: могу обновить вопрос со всем `onCreate`

Comment: @Andrew Goroshko желательно